# How to sniff Ion library request to rest server

Tags: android, asynchronous, fiddler, sniffing, android-ion

I'm using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) for checking and sniffing my apps request to rest server, It's work perfectly.

But in my last app I'm using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) Library for Asynchronous Networking and Image Loading. When I create any request ( as POST -or- GET ), I can't monitor and see anything!!

Is anybody there that know how can handle this?! or cause of this issue?!

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the proxy configuration steps required? https://github.com/koush/ion#proxy-servers-like-charles-proxy

`Ion.getDefault(context).configure().proxy("mycomputer", 8888);`

You also need to ensure that `Allow remote computers to connect` setting is enabled in Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections.

Comment: I tried this method using my computers name liliana-pc, localhost, and 127.0.0.1 and i keep getting errors --> Unable to resolve host "liliana-pc": No address associated with hostname & java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "liliana-pc": No address associated with hostname

Comment: @user1743524: Neither `localhost` nor `127.0.0.1` will work from Android, because both of those of course refer to the Android device. If `Liliana-pc` doesn't work that means that your DNS isn't configured properly. Instead, use the IP address of the external interface of your PC. Hover over the Network icon at the top-right of Fiddler to see the IP.